# jQuery Checkbox Filters - From OR to AND

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. I've been playing with some code I found here on SO, but I'm a little bit confused as to how the javascript portion works.

Currently, if you check more than 1 check box, it will pick all results that match. I want to have it match only if both check boxes are true, not listing all when it's one or the other.

Java

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

            $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
                $('.results > li').hide();
                $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                    $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                });
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
<div class="tags">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="PVC" />PVC</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="316SS" />316SS</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="PVDF" />PVDF</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="Other" />Other</label>
</div>

<ul class="results">
    <li class="PVC">Result 1 (PVC Only)</li>
    <li class="316SS">Result 2 (316SS Only)</li>
    <li class="PVDF">Result 3 (PVDF Only)</li>
    <li class="Other">Result 4 (Other Only)</li>
    <li class="PVC PVDF">Result 5 (PVC & PVDF)</li>
    <li class="316SS PVDF">Result 6 (316SS & PVDF)</li>
    <li class="PVDF Other">Result 7 (PVDF & Other)</li>
    <li class="PVC 316SS PVDF Other">Result 8 (All Classes)</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xubp8atd/)

So from my JSFiddle, you can see if you check PVC & PVDF, all the results for PVC come up, as do all the results for PVDF. In that particular case when 2 or more boxes are checked, I want it to match only the results that have **both** PVC & PVDF in their class, not one or the other. Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .filter() like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checks = $('div.tags input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var $results = $('.results > li').hide();
    $checks.filter(':checked').each(function() {
      $results = $results.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel'))
    });
    $results.show();
  });

  //set the initial display state
  $checks.eq(0).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label><input type="checkbox" rel="PVC" />PVC</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" rel="316SS" />316SS</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" rel="PVDF" />PVDF</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" rel="Other" />Other</label>
</div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="PVC">Result 1 (PVC Only)</li>
  <li class="316SS">Result 2 (316SS Only)</li>
  <li class="PVDF">Result 3 (PVDF Only)</li>
  <li class="Other">Result 4 (Other Only)</li>
  <li class="PVC PVDF">Result 5 (PVC & PVDF)</li>
  <li class="316SS PVDF">Result 6 (316SS & PVDF)</li>
  <li class="PVDF Other">Result 7 (PVDF & Other)</li>
  <li class="PVC 316SS PVDF Other">Result 8 (All Classes)</li>
</ul>
```